# Why should I drop a table before creating it again?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax

If I want to create a table, why should I drop it first if it already exists, and then `CREATE`?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GAME;
CREATE Table GAME();
```

Comment: Remove the DROP - then consider the result. You may wish to see [CREATE .. IF NOT EXISTS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtable.html). In any case, think of how terrible it would be if CREATE TABLE could just overwrite an existing schema!

Comment: Why would you want to create a table that already exists?

Answer (score 3):

Because you'll get an error if you try to create a table that already exists.

Comment: IT s clear that i get an error, but i dont understand the sense of the compiler and error

Comment: Then perhaps you should update your question to ask about what you actually want to know?

Comment: @user3669866 . . . You should ask another *better* question.  If you edit this question, you might invalidate this answer, which is unfair to the author of the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually, I agree -- I answered the question, I should get a tick :)

Comment: You get a comment upvote from me for being smart. :) But this question should be removed entirely.